# AjaxResponseRenderer in tapestry 5.1

Tags: java, ajax, tapestry

I am working in a project with **Tapestry 5.1**
I have a problem injecting AjaxResponseRenderer because it doesnt exist in **Tapestry 5.1**

Here is what I want to do ***Myclass.java***

```
@Inject 
private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;

 void onValueChangedFromCarMake(String carMake) {

    // A new make has been chosen - clear the model.

    carModel = null;
    carModels = NO_MODELS;

    // Show the models of the chosen make.

    if (carMake != null) {
        if (carMake.equals(MAKE_HONDA)) {
            carModels = HONDA_MODELS;
        }
        else if (carMake.equals(MAKE_TOYOTA)) {
            carModels = TOYOTA_MODELS;
        }
    }

    if (request.isXHR()) {
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(carModelZone);
    }
}
```

[this is a live exemple on what i want to do](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/select1)

I don't have the right to upgrade Tapestry version

Can you please tell me how I can do that in another way ?

Comment: Any problems using http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ajax/MultiZoneUpdate.html ? AjaxResponseRenderer should be doing the same thing since 5.3

Comment: I did some research on MultiZoneUpdate and I can't find any exemple , so I tried to do the same as AjaxResponseRenderer by calling MultiZoneUpdate.add("idZone",Obj), but It didn"t work

Comment: I think you need to return an instance of the `MultiZoneUpdate` from event handler instead of just adding the zones to the instance as with AjaxResponseRenderer. An example can be found in tapestry sources for your version, i.e. here: https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/5.1.0.x-dev/tapestry-core/src/test/java/org/apache/tapestry5/integration/app1/pages/MultiZoneUpdateDemo.java